# Flip armature animation direction (from Mixamo to Blender (2.77))

Tags: animation, armature, nla-editor

Hi I am having trouble trying to combine multiple animations downloaded from Mixamo and imported into Blender via .fbx.

Everything imports correctly but some of the animations I need to combine in the NLA are animating in the opposite direction to each other. I cannot figure out how to flip the direction (eg. from +y to -y) of an animated armature (there are hundreds of keyframes).

[image]

(I've tried parenting another 'Direction' Bone to the armature and key-framing the rotation at certain points but this still does not work because of the offset distance between bones during the animation.)

Any help or ideas appreciated! 
Here's an example blend file... https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BzkKNZyqdUhXc3N3RVg3YVZmUTA&usp=sharing

Comment: have you tried to change the fbx import options ?

Comment: Could you also upload the fbx file, though ?

Comment: Sure just added them to the folder link... it appears that the NLA editor only relies on the pose keyframe location / rotation (guessing), rotating the armature doesn't help.

Comment: I found a solution, add an extra bone and keyframe the pose position and rotation... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Soyra9kRo6g 
I was close before but wasn't keyframing in pose mode.
The only problem with this is that you can't blend NLA strips so the animation is not smooth between strips.